# POCO: parthandler adds extra CR

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

C++ Poco Net library provides a feature to upload the file to server. Here is the snippet

```
void handlePart(const MessageHeader& header, std::istream& stream)
{
    _type = header.get("Content-Type", "(unspecified)");
    if (header.has("Content-Disposition"))
    {
        std::string disp;
        NameValueCollection params;
        MessageHeader::splitParameters(header["Content-Disposition"], disp, params);
        _name = params.get("name", "(unnamed)");
        _fileName = params.get("filename", "(unnamed)");
    }

    CountingInputStream istr(stream);
    NullOutputStream ostr;
    StreamCopier::copyStream(istr, ostr);
    _length = istr.chars();
}
```

now the problem is that on saving the file ( on redirecting stream to file), an extra "CR" is being added to each line of file. This is what is saved on the server side.

```
2013-02-12 14:14:00 ICVUPDO -- START

2013-02-12 14:14:00 GetCommandLine() = C:\Windows\INCOPS3\icvupdo.exe -pull

2013-02-12 14:14:00 _GetParameters() = -pull

2013-02-12 14:14:00 Run by PULL_MODE
```

Although, I had sent this -

```
2013-02-12 14:14:00 ICVUPDO -- START
2013-02-12 14:14:00 GetCommandLine() = C:\Windows\INCOPS3\icvupdo.exe -pull
2013-02-12 14:14:00 _GetParameters() = -pull
2013-02-12 14:14:00 Run by PULL_MODE
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Issue is resolved. All I had to do was -opening the file in "binary" mode to write buffer into it.